# Need regex to extract only alphabets from string

Tags: c#, regex, extract

Hi I have string like `A01`, `AAA`, etc.

I want to extract out the alphabet part of it like for `A01` => `A`, `AAA` => `AAA`.

I am using `[A-Za-z\s]` but it does not work. It however works when I try online at 
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

What is missing?

Comment: Not getting. I am using c#:                                                        
            Regex regexb = new Regex("[A-Za-z\\s]");
            string sx1 = regexb.Match("AAA").Value;

Comment: An + operator is missing. Check my answer. Why do you need `\\s` ? This meta charracter matches blank characters(tabs, spaces etc).

Comment: you need to tag `regex` questions with the **language** u r using..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here an agnostic language regex solution :

```
/[a-z]+/i
```

C# code :

```
public Regex MyRegex = new Regex( "[a-z]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I tried this in my code above. It retruns empty string. Does not work.. any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ, as regex involves overhead:

```
var res = String.Join("", input.Where(c => Char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that will work surely.

```
string txt="a123b";
        string re1="([A-Za-z])";

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(txt, re1);

    string str = String.Empty;

        // Use foreach loop.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            foreach (Capture capture in match.Captures)
                {
                    str += capture.Value ;
                }
        }
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

use System.Text.RegularExpression namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex replace.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string aplhaNumericString = "A01", alphabeticalString ="AAA";

Regex.Replace(aplhaNumericString,@"\d","");
Regex.Replace(alphabeticalString,@"\d","");
```